# How to solve this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How do I use ERO's to solve this matrix? I know there won't be solutions, but how do I approach this? Many thanks.

[image: Matrix]

Comment: What is ERO? What does it mean to "solve a matrix"? What have you tried? Do you know what this equation means? What difficulties do you have? Which of the myriads of documents on the internet or in books about this topic have you consulted? What remains difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That system is equivalent to this system :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&2\\0&1&3\\0&0&0\\0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2\\ \alpha_3 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which means (in the third equation) that $0\alpha_1+0\alpha_2+0\alpha_3=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: The right side not true.

Comment: What part exactly?

Comment: The vector $(3,-1,0,-1)^T$

Comment: Sure! Thank you for correcting me, I can't believe I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

There are no solutions to $\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&1\\-1&1&1\\3&1&9\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ since $2\alpha_1-\alpha_2+\alpha_3-\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=2$ and $2\alpha_1-\alpha_2+\alpha_3+3\alpha_1+\alpha_2+9\alpha_3=3\neq 10$